# Confused about computer specifications regarding maximum RAM amount

Tags: memory

Here is my [computer](http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c02056471). I have 2x2 GB RAM installed. Specification says that it can support 8 GB, but there is a note saying "At the time of this publication HP has not qualified SO-DIMMs larger than 2.0 GB for use with this motherboard. Higher capacity modules may be qualified at a later date."

So I can't have more than 4 GB?

Answer (score 0):

Answer in short is YES.

You should be able to install 2x4gb Ram Sticks.

Here are some Compatible Modules [Upgrade Kit for 8Gb Total](http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/touchsmart-300-1125/CT5311367)

There are many other Compatible with your Computer Just do a Search of you model and type in `touchsmart-300-1125 8gb of ram`

At the Time they only tested with 2x2gb SO-DIMMs but they had to have tested with 8gb at some point or the Maximum Memory allowed would not have been set at 8gb.